# Javascript: Using Math.random in functions nested in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write an app that will deliver combined results from multiple random selections.  I am using 2 dimensional arrays.  The first element of each secondary array is the number to 'roll' less than, to return the secondary array, which contains a string as its second element.

Further, inside the string is usually another function which calls another array.

All the returned strings are concatenated into a random phrase.

My expectation was that each time every function was called a new random result would be given.  But what seems to be happening is once the first function call returns a result all nested function calls return the same result each time.  What I would like is for each nested function call to return a new random result each time.

I hope I'm explaining this well enough.   Here is some of the code I'm using with some 'sample' arrays to try to make clear what I'm doing.

```
// ROLL()
// times = NUMBER OF TIMES TO ROLL
// high = SIZE OF THE DIE / HIGHEST VALUE TO ROLL
// low = LOWEST VALUE (OPTIONAL)
// modifier = MODIFIER TO ROLL (OPTIONAL)

function roll(times, high, low, modifier) {
  low = low || 1;
  modifier = modifier || 0;
  var result = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    result += (Math.floor(Math.random() * ((high - low) + 1) + low));
  }
  result += modifier;

  return result;
}

// RANDOMRESULT()
// array = A 2 DIM ARRAY
// modifier = MODIFIER TO ROLL (FOR THE ROLL() FUNCTION)
// dieSize = SIZE OF THE DIE (FOR THE ROLL() FUNCTION)

function randomResult(array, modifier, dieSize) {
  var die = dieSize || array[array.length - 1][0];
  var finalRoll = roll(1, die, 1, modifier);

  for (i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
    if (finalRoll <= array[i][0]) {
      return array[i];
    }
  }
}

//ASSUME MULTIPLE ARRAYS SET UP SIMILARLY
var array1 = [
  [3, "You find " + roll(1, 10) + " dollars."],
  [5, "You find " + roll(1, 20) + " dollars."],
  [9, "You find " + roll(1, 30) + " dollars."]
];

var array2 = [...]

var someArray = [
  [2, "Random result from array1. " + randomResult(array1)],
  [4, "Random result from array2. " + randomResult(array2)],
  [10, "Random result from array3. " + randomResult(array3)]
];

console.log(randomResult(someArray));
console.log(randomResult(someArray));
```

EDIT:  The results are always random for each page refresh but when the randomResult() is called multiple times the same results occur from the nested array functions.
example of muliptle console.log returns...

```
(2) [2, "Random result from array1. 9,You find 1 dollars."]
(2) [10, "Random result from array3. 9,You find 2 dollars."]
(2) [10, "Random result from array3. 9,You find 2 dollars."]
(2) [2, "Random result from array1. 9,You find 1 dollars."]
(2) [10, "Random result from array3. 9,You find 2 dollars."]
(2) [4, "Random result from array2. 9,You find 2 dollars."]
```

So every time a '2' or less is rolled the roll() function from array1 always returns the same value.  Same with the other results and the other arrays.

So my questions are first, why is this happening?  Maybe because the first function call hasn't finished when the second is made?
Second are there any suggestions to fix this.  Using object methods instead of 2 dim arrays maybe?

Any commentary or help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I check your array1 and it indeed has a random roll result. So I am not sure what is your problem. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call randomResult() multiple time, it refer back to the array1 and the value of array1 is already calculated when the script is loaded.
If you want a different value each time, put it inside a function and call the function to get the value.

```
function getRandomArray() {
    return  [
    [3, "You find " + roll(1, 10) + " dollars."],
    [5, "You find " + roll(1, 20) + " dollars."],
    [9, "You find " + roll(1, 30) + " dollars."]
    ];
}
console.log(getRandomArray());
console.log(getRandomArray());
```

Comment: Ah!  Thanks.  I knew I should have taken a break.  Not sure why that didn't click with me.  Appreciate you taking the time to answer.